# Insert from source database into destination database, different servers

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 database servers, a source and destination.

I've recently cloned 2 tables from the source to the destination and I have a script that is using the max id of destination table to insert everything after it from the source. This is run every 5 minutes as a rough approach to update the data on the destination server.

It's missing records though so I'm hoping for a different approach.

I want to select all from the source table, and if the id doesn't exist in the destination then insert it. I have no idea the best way to do this but I need something accurate so that it won't miss records anymore.

Here's the current script:

```
$latest_result_summary = $conn2->query("
        SELECT MAX(`NOTABLECALLID`) FROM `ambition`.`callsummary`");
$latest_row_summary = $latest_result_summary->fetch_row();
$latest_summary_id = $latest_row_summary[0];

//select All rows from the source phone database(callsummary)
$source_data_summary = mysqli_query($conn, "
        SELECT * FROM `cdrdb`.`callsummary` 
        WHERE `NOTABLECALLID` > $latest_summary_id");

// Loop on the results
while($source_summary = $source_data_summary->fetch_assoc()) {

        // Check if row exists in destination phone database, cdrdb.callsummary
        $row_exists_summary = $conn2->query("
                SELECT NOTABLECALLID FROM ambition.callsummary 
                WHERE NOTABLECALLID = '".$source_summary['NOTABLECALLID']."' ")
        or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

        //if query returns false, rows don't exist with that new ID.
        if ($row_exists_summary->num_rows == 0){

                //Insert new rows into ambition.callsummary
                $stmt_summary = $conn2->prepare("
                        INSERT INTO ambition.callsummary 
                        (NOTABLECALLID, STARTTIME, ENDTIME, DURATION, 
                         ANSWERED, ts, firstcallid)
                        VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
                or die(mysqli_error($conn2)) ;

                mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_summary, "issiisi", 
                        $source_summary['NOTABLECALLID'], 
                        $source_summary['STARTTIME'],
                        $source_summary['ENDTIME'], 
                        $source_summary['DURATION'],
                        $source_summary['ANSWERED'], 
                        $source_summary['ts'],
                        $source_summary['firstcallid'] 
                );

                $stmt_summary->execute() or die(mysqli_error($conn2));


        }
}
```

The key here is we're not setup with our dba and phone system to preform replication, so I just need a good accurate way to insert to destination if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks like php code.  Write a stored procedure to do the data transfer and call it with php.  Or, if MySQL supports it, schedule the stored procedure to run at the appropriate interval.

Comment: @DanBracuk, a stored procedure cannot transfer data between servers.

Comment: Yes, as I stated above I have this running in a script (php) but it is transferring from one server to another, identical tables

Comment: You *may* or may not be able to rig up your destination server so it can read the source server's table via MySQL FEDERATION. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/federated-create.html  Then you could create queries to read from the source table and insert / update the destination table.

Comment: @BillKarwin, why can't a stored procedure transfer data between servers?

Comment: @DanBracuk, this question is about MySQL. In MySQL, stored procedures have no way to connect to different server. Procedures can access only tables on the server where the procedure runs. Are you thinking of some other RDBMS, like Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `mysqldump`.

1. Find the greatest NOTABLECALLID and store it in variable `$latest_summary_id` as you are doing now.
2. Dump the data from the source database, but with options to limit the data to the rows greater than `$latest_summary_id`. Also use the INSERT IGNORE so it will skip any existing rows without throwing an error. And of course don't include drop/create statements for the destination table!

   ```
   mysqldump cdrdb callsummary
     --host sourcedbhost
     --single-transaction 
     --no-create-info 
     --insert-ignore 
     --where "notablecallid > $latest_summary_id"
     > callsummary-YYMMDD.sql
   ```
3. Import dump to destination database:

   ```
   mysql
     --host destdbhost
     --execute "source callsummary-YYMMDD.sql"
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but unfortunately, I've now discovered a new issue.......access denied for creating tables and dumping from source database. This is applied by the phone system manager. Looks like I'll have to go another route

Comment: Couldn't I potentially do a select * on the table and hold those values, then do an insert ignore into my dest. table?

Comment: Yes, you can do an INSERT IGNORE on the destination table. Then you don't have to do a SELECT first to see if the row exists (which is a race condition anyway).

Comment: Thank you, I'm accepting your answer because I know it would have worked but also helped point me in the right direction. I"m now just selecting * from source where the timestamp is today and doing an insert ignore. Thanks again!